# Cloning a repo as a submodule to my project

Tags: git, github, repository, git-submodules

I'm trying to clone a folder to my node.js project from someone's github. When I clone it I use the `git submodule add <repo link>`.

After I do this, I modify the url inside the .gitmodules folder to point it to my github repo.

When I add, commit and push the changes, the folder that I just added will have a blue text and when I click on it it will point me to the github profile from where I got it from. Also, if I make any changes to it and try to push them, it will tell me that everything is up to date.

I tried `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main my-branch`  but it didn't work.

It seems like there is something very important that I'm missing and can't quite figure it.